# Remove type inside the freebase suggested list

Tags: jquery, freebase

Is it possible to remove the type of research (for example 'Film'), inside the list of items returned from freebase jQuery suggestion?

Thanks for your attention.
Simone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using CSS?

```
<style>
 .fbs-item-type { display:none; }
</style>
```